# Postgres Find and Return Keywords From List Within Select

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search, keyword-search, array-agg

I have a simple postgres table that contains a comments (text) column.
Within a view, I need to search that comments field for a list of words and then return a comma separated list of the words found as a column (as well as a bunch of normal columns).

The list of defined keywords contains about 20 words. I.e. apples, bananas, pear, peach, plum.

Ideal result would be something like:

```
id | comments                    | keywords
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | I like bananas!             | bananas
2  | I like apples.              | apples
3  | I don't like fruit          | 
4  | I like apples and bananas!  | apples,bananas
```

I'm thinking I need to do a sub query and array_agg? Or possibly 'where in'. But I can't figure out how to bolt it together.

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: How do you know what a keyword is and what not?

Comment: What do you mean @a_horse_with_no_name ? I have defined list of keywords to look for - about 20 of them I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use full-text search facilities to achieve results:

1. Setup new [ispell dictionary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY) with your list of words.
2. Create [full-text search configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-configuration.html) which will be based on your dictionary. Don't forget to remove all other dictionaries from configuration, because in your case all other words actually are stopwords.

After that when you execute

```
select plainto_tsquery('<your config name>', 'I like apples and bananas!')
```

you will get only your keywords: `'apples' & 'bananas'` or even `'apple' & 'banana'` if you setup dictionary properly.

By default, english configuration uses snowball dictionaries which reduce word endings, so if you run

```
select plainto_tsquery('english', 'I like apples and bananas!')
```

you will get

```
'like' & 'appl' & 'banana'
```

which is not exact suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks @TnT - that's very helpful. I have made good progress on this - but i'm getting BOTH my words returned AND other stuff such as numbers and unknown phrases (i.e. 100, 10pm, etc).

Is there a way of ignoring EVERYTHING except my word list?

Comment: My config so far:

     CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.nrw ( COPY = pg_catalog.english );

     CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY nrw_dict_ispell (
          TEMPLATE = ispell,
          DictFile = nrw_dict,
          AffFile = nrw_dict
    );

     ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION nrw
          DROP MAPPING FOR email, url, url_path, sfloat, float, int;

     ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION nrw
          ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, word, hword, hword_part
          WITH nrw_dict_ispell;

Comment: Got around the issues with the the numbers by doing a regex_replace. Once the numbers were striped out the key words were returned perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Another easier way (but slower):

create dict table:

```
create table keywords (nm text);

insert into keywords (nm)
values ('apples'), ('bananas');
```

Execute the following script against your text to extract keywords

```
select string_agg(regexp_replace(foo, '[^a-zA-Z\-]*', '', 'ig'), ',') s
  from regexp_split_to_table('I like apples and bananas!', E'\\s+') foo 
 where regexp_replace(foo, '[^a-zA-Z\-]*', '', 'ig') in (select nm from keywords)
```

This solution is worse in terms of semantic, so banana and bananas will be different keywords.